# Get full router pattern when using child routers in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I request the HTTP endpoint `GET /foobar/baz` in the following Express app, how do I - via the `req` object - get the original pattern used to match the entire URL (i.e. `/foo(bar)?/:id`):

```
var app = express()
var sub = express.Router()

sub.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   // if `/foobar/baz` is requested:
   console.log(req.url)         // '/baz'
   console.log(req.baseUrl)     // '/foobar'
   console.log(req.originalUrl) // '/foobar/baz'
   console.log(req.route.path)  // '/:id'
})

app.use('/foo(bar)?', sub)
```

It's possible to access the sub-route pattern using `req.route.path` which gives me `/:id`, but the parent route pattern `/foo(bar)?` seems unobtainable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`mountpath`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.mountpath) property

> The `app.mountpath` property is the path pattern(s) on which a sub app
>   was mounted.

```
var app = express()
var sub = express.Router()

sub.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   // if `/foobar/baz` is requested:

    console.log( sub.mountpath ); // '/foo(bar)?'

    console.log(req.route.path)         // '/:id'

})

app.use('/foo(bar)?', sub);
```

Comment: I don't have access to the `sub` variable without some serious hackery. Would have hoped that there were some way of getting it via `req` :(

Comment: Hmm.. I'm using Express 4.13 and it seems that `sub.mountpath` is undefined here